# unable to veriify a signed message in solidity

Tags: solidity, web3.py

## behaviour of web3py and solidity.

Samples:

```
## First in web3py

sig = Web3.soliditySha3( [uint256], [tokens] ) ## used below also
output: HexBytes('0x3efb3cf4e41109f6f1f998401d02dbe894719a8806f45e79a5fab7d4799f00bb')
```

```
from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct
msg = sig.hex()
message = encode_defunct(text=msg)
signed_message = w3.eth.account.sign_message(message, private_key=private_key)
signed_message

SignedMessage(messageHash=HexBytes('0x4c0c7077f770069785167e8b7451d63fad1e858ef5251b239eb0781c314000d2'), r=5665764915496639843348851536709769469640799172147461427941649091688603148258, s=48121517563314450138554207713326165180739298862566159641495137088718857193470, v=27, signature=HexBytes('0x0c86b594baa5bb06a0f4054ffdf3896377cfb757d42dcaeacf0241d96a4d5fe26a63d0514338ec600c89ee808dc088e7b3aadc55b9f5d86685d3ff212e2e47fe1b'))
```

Then I tried

```
w3.eth.account.recoverHash(signed_message.messagehash,signature=signed_message.signature)#gives correct contract address as output
```

But when I use:

```
w3.eth.account.recoverHash(sig,signature=signed_message.signature) ## gives incorrect address
```

But it gives the same address which solidity is giving...

then I checked what is the output of `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(..))`.
I found It is same as sig value

and then the `ecrecover` output of solidity gives the same address given by the above function..

How can I validate properly the tokens that I owe.

Please help..